# How Many Rows Can A Listbox Hold? Windows Form Application

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have over 9,00,000 records in my Access database but only a fraction of that is being displayed in the listbox. How Many Rows Can A Listbox Hold? Around 65K is the answer I got from my research.
Thanks!

Comment: What is a user supposed to do with 900k entries in *any* UI element?

Comment: Perhaps you should rethink your interface. Displaying 900k records to a user in one screen is overwhelming and probably useless. Consider narrowing down what you will display to something more useful at less than a hundred.

Comment: @ Alex K. @ Bueller - I know it doesn't make sense. but it is the need of the hour :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the exact limit is (The url provided below gives some suggestions) I think the number of items you want to populate the listbox with will probably slow your computer down alot if it's populating it with that many records.

Maybe you should consider using a different control that allows paging like a DataGrid or something similar to display 100 results at a time?

This link might be useful to you: http://codeguru.earthweb.com/forum/showthread.php?p=1715288

Creating datagrid with paging: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305271

Comment: If I use datagrid is there a way in which I can move selected items to a different textarea or listbox?

Comment: You could add code to highlight the rows you want to select (or use checkboxes in a column and check the items you want to move) and then click a button which will execute a foreach to loop through the selected items and add them to another controls item source. This link might be useful for highlighting the rows in the data grid http://support.microsoft.com/kb/195472

Answer (score 3):

There is a bug in the native listbox control that was introduced at Vista time and is still present in Win7.  It prevents you from scrolling properly past 65536 + number of visible items.  The most visible part of the bug, beyond not seeing the later items, is the scrollbar thumb jumping back when you drag it to the bottom.

This bug doesn't get put to the test very often.  Nobody ever expects his user to have enough patience to claw through tens of thousands of items.  Such a program gets uninstalled quickly.  ListBox capacity is otherwise only limited by the amount of available virtual memory.  If you really want to pursue this then use ListView or DataGridView.

Comment: Also look at virtual mode if you choose to use a WF listview http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.virtualmode.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I've found it preferable to use DataGridView over ListBox in winforms. The key is to use VirtualMode. I'd derive from DataGridView similar to:

```
class CustomDgv : DataGridView {
    public CustomDgv() {
        this.BackgroundColor = SystemColors.Window;
        this.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
        this.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.MultiSelect = false;
        this.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        this.RowHeadersVisible = this.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;

        this.ReadOnly = true;
        this.AllowUserToAddRows = this.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
        this.CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.None;

        this.VirtualMode = true;
        this.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;

        this.RowTemplate.Height = this.FontHeight + this.FontHeight / 2;
    }
}
```

and then implement the virtual part accordingly.